# Ruby - Invalid Regex

Tags: ruby, regex

Ruby 1.8.7 says:

```
/Users/user/.thor/916bf40c98406efffe9700e1ef02da24:194: undefined (?...) sequence: /(?<text>Version:)\s*(?<version>[\d\.]+)/
```

Ruby 1.9.3-p374 says something similar, but Ruby 1.9.3-p0 works just fine with it.

The actual code that's broken:

```
pattern = /(?<text>Version:)\s*(?<version>[\d\.]+)/
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: How about - what did I do wrong with the pattern ?

Comment: Don't use regex for HTML, use [nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) or a similar, dedicated parser instead

Comment: Not parsing HTML. I'm parsing a CSS file with very predictable content "Version: 10.10.10" for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `(?<k>...)` notation expresses named capture, which was introduced in Ruby 1.9, which uses Oniguruma regex engine. With Ruby 1.8, you need to either change the regex to not use it, or install Oniguruma or Onigmo (an improved version of Oniguruma introduced in Ruby 2.0).

Comment: But why did I get an error in 1.9.3-p374 then ? I assumed I had something wrong with my regex there.

Comment: I think what is happening is as what Darshan writes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
Updated ruby, everything works out fine.

Comment: Good. I hope you updated to Ruby 2.0 because there is less reason to not switch from 1.9 to 2.0 than not to switch from 1.8 to 1.9.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine for me in Ruby 1.9.3-p374.  I suspect that what you are doing wrong is still running 1.8.7 when you think you're using 1.9.3-p374.  As noted by @sawa, your regex is using a feature introduced in 1.9.

Comment: That was weird. Now after a couple of rvm implodes I've managed to get everything straight. Thanks.